# Responsive Issue with my website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I asked this question before, but it was too confusing and I couldn't clarify it as well. I fixed my website and now doing test to make my responsive site work on different mobile platform. However, when open the site on Android mobile, everything is fall apart.
For responsive design, I am using external file and linking it to html like this.

here is the website http://www.sfu.ca/~nnabeel   use mobile to open the site.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width:786px)" href="medium-style.css" /> <!--Tablet-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:500px)" href="small-style.css" /> <!--Mobile-->
```

I am using meta-tag to make the site scale able to different platforms.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimun-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Here is my HTML/CSS code for responsive design.

HTML:

```
<body>


    <div id="controls">

        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="work.html">Work</a>
        <a href="contact.html">About</a>


    </div>


    <div id="pagewrap">

        <div id="home">

            <article>

                <img src="images/Logo.png" width="150" height="150" alt="Logo"/>
                <p>My name is Nabeel Muhammad and I change innovative ideas into design </p>

                <div id="socialmedia">

                    <a href="https://twitter.com/mnabeel87" target="new"> <img src="images/twitter.jpg" height="40" width="40" alt="Twitter Logo"/></a>

                    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/mnabeel87" target="new"> <img src="images/linkedin.jpg" height="40" width="40" alt="Linkedin Logo"/> </a>

                </div> <!--Social Media Ends-->
            </article>  

            <div id="skillslevel"><p>Skills Level</p></div>


            <section>
                <div id="psskills"> <img src="images/photoshop.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Adobe PhotoShop" /> </div>
                <div id="psrating"> </div>

                <div id="aiskills">  <img src="images/illustrator.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Adobe Illustrator" /> </div>
                <div id="airating" > </div>

                <div id="inskills"> <img src="images/indesign.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Adobe InDesign" /> </div>
                <div id="inrating"0> </div>

                <div id="dwskills"> <img src="images/dremweaver.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Adobe DreamWeaver" /> </div>
                <div id="dwrating"> </div>

                <div id="prskills"> <img src="images/premier.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Adobe DreamWeaver" /> </div>
                <div id="prrating"> </div>

                <div id="htmlskills"> <img src="images/html.png" width="30" height="40" alt="Adobe DreamWeaver" /> </div>
                <div id="htmlrating"> </div>

                <div id="cssskills"> <img src="images/css.png" width="30" height="40" alt="Adobe DreamWeaver" /> </div>
                <div id="cssrating"> </div>

                <div id="jsskills"> <img src="images/javascript.png" width="30" height="40" alt="Adobe DreamWeaver" /> </div>
                <div id="jsrating"> </div>

                <div id="jqskills"> <img src="images/jquery.png" width="30" height="40" alt="Adobe DreamWeaver" /> </div>
                <div id="jqrating"> </div>

            </section>

            <div id="scale"> <img src="images/linebar.png"  width="330" alt="Scale"/> </div>  
            <div id="ratingnumber">
                <ul>
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>5</li>
                    <li>10</li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        </div> <!--Home Ends-->

    </div>
```

CSS for mobile

```
#pagewrap {
    width: 480px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.6em;
    position:relative;
}


#controls {
    margin:-0.3em auto 0 -0.3em;
    text-align: center;
    width:480px;
    font-family: 'Bebas';
    font-size:1.87em;
    background-color: #b0d8a3;

    line-height:1.3em;
}

#controls a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #5cc3c1;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 32px;
}


#home article img {
    position:relative;
    left:3em;
    top:4em;
}

#home article p {
    font-size:2.5em;
    font-family: 'Bebas';
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    width:10em;
    left:1em;
    top:1em;
    line-height:1.1em;
    padding: 0 0;


}
#socialmedia {
    position: relative;
    top:-1.8em;
    left:-0.5em;
    margin-right:1em;

}

#socialmedia img {
    position:absolute;
    left:8em;
    top: 2.5em;


}



/*Skills*/

#skillslevel {
    position:absolute;
    top:25em;
    left:2.5em;

}

#skillslevel p {
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-family: 'Cabin';
}

section {
    position: relative;
    bottom:22.5em;
}

section #psskills {
    position: absolute;
    left:2.5em;
    top:27em;

}

section #psrating {
    width: 20.3em;
    height: 2.3em;
    background: #bfddc3;
    position: absolute;
    left:5.5em;
    top:27em;
}

section #aiskills {
    position: absolute;
    left:2.5em;
    top:30em;

}

section #airating {
    width:18.6em;
    height:2.3em;
    background-color: #bfddc3;
    position: absolute ;
    left: 5.5em;
    top:30em;
}

section #inskills {
    position:absolute;
    left:2.5em;
    top:33em;
}

section #inrating {
    width:19.3em;
    height:2.3em;
    background-color: #bfddc3;
    position: absolute ;
    left: 5.5em;
    top:33em;
}

section #dwskills {
    position:absolute;
    left:2.5em;
    top:36em;
}

section #dwrating {
    width:19.8em;
    height:2.3em;
    background-color: #bfddc3;
    position: absolute ;
    left: 5.5em;
    top:36em;
}

section #prskills {
    position:absolute;
    left:2.5em;
    top:39em;
}

section #prrating {
    width:19.3em;
    height:2.3em;
    background-color: #bfddc3;
    position: absolute ;
    left: 5.5em;
    top:39em;
}

section #htmlskills {
    position:absolute;
    left:2.5em;
    top:42em;
}

section #htmlrating {
    width:20.3em;
    height:2.3em;
    background-color: #adc8bf;
    position: absolute ;
    left: 5.5em;
    top:42em;
}

section #cssskills {
    position:absolute;
    left:2.5em;
    top:45em;
}

section #cssrating {
    width:20.3em;
    height:2.3em;
    background-color: #adc8bf;
    position: absolute ;
    left: 5.5em;
    top:45em;
}

section #jsskills {
    position:absolute;
    left:2.5em;
    top:48em;
}

section #jsrating {
    width:14.3em;
    height:2.3em;
    background-color: #adc8bf;
    position: absolute ;
    left: 5.5em;
    top:48em;
}

section #jqskills {
    position:absolute;
    left:2.5em;
    top:51em;
}

section #jqrating {
    width:12.3em;
    height:2.3em;
    background-color: #adc8bf;
    position: absolute ;
    left: 5.5em;
    top:51em;
}

#scale {
    position:absolute;
    top:48.5em;
    left:5.2em;




}

#ratingnumber ul{
    position:absolute;
    top:57em;
    left:-6em;
    list-style:none;


}

#ratingnumber ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:9em;
    font-family: 'Cabin'; 
    font-size:16px;

}
```

I know its alot of CSS, some of you might find some of the things useless, but that is how I approach the problem.

So when I open the website in tablet, it works fine, but as soon as I open it in mobile, the design fell apart.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed in your viewport you've spelt minimum in minimum-scale incorrectly.

This will break the scaling.